# Counting all files in folder and subfolder

Tags: vb.net, count, directory

I am using visual basic and I want to count all the files that exist in a folder and in its subfolders.. I tried this :

`Dim counter = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\Folder")
MsgBox("number of files is " & CStr(counter.Count))`

but it only counts files in the *C:\Folder* and **not** in *C:\Folder\Sub-Folder\AnotherSubFolder*
What should I do?
Thank's for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Directory.GetFiles()` as defined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx

So you'd just use

```
Dim counter As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(someString, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
MsgBox("Number of files is : " + counter)
```

`someString` being the top-level directory you want to start at

`"*.*"` being the search pattern you want to match. This gets all files. If you wanted only text files, for example, you could do `"*.txt"`.

`SearchOption` enum has two options: `AllDirectories` or `TopDirectoryOnly` if you're **only** interested in the exact directory passed, obviously.

Comment: Thank's a lot,that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Don't want to be that guy, but I think `*.*` would only get files with a dot inside their name. So files like "ImHiding" which have no and filetype defined wouldn't be counted, would they? ..just a little exploit unlikely to happen.

Comment: @Luke I thought you might be right, but I just tested it. It still finds extension-less files. [See screenshot of output here](http://i.imgur.com/nJlliD4.png).

Comment: That's unexpected. +1 for trying out :-)

Comment: @Luke [This](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filesystemenumerable.cs,c026d69ba22f8681,references) is the method that gets called on the string. I'm not sure *exactly* what `searchPattern.TrimEnd(Path.TrimEndChars)` does but I'd wager it removes any asterisks, and then sees that it's just a single `.` which gets replaced with a single `*` in the `if` statement. But yes, unexpected IMO.