# Count all files in folder and subfolder with VB6

Tags: count, directory, vb6, subdirectory

In VB6, I am using a Webbrowser form to display all files and subfolders as icons in the style of Windows Explorer. On the form, I display a count of all files in the main folder and all subfolders. This is my code so far, though haven't been able to find any information about counting subfolders.

```
Private Sub Load_Form()      
    Dim myPathName as String
    Dim iTotalCount as Long
    some stuff here ....
    WebBrowser1.Navigate myPathName
    WebBrowser1.Document.CurrentViewMode = 5   'medium icons
    iTotalCount = FileCount(myPathName)
    lblLabel.Caption = "Total Files = " & iTotalCount
    more stuff here ....
End Sub

Public Function FileCount(myPathName as String) as Long
    Dim FSO as New FileSystemObject
    Dim fld as Folder
    If FSO.FolderExists(myPathName) Then
        Set fld = FSO.GetFolder(myPathName)
        FileCount = fld.Files.Count
    End If
End Function
```

[This StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277848/counting-all-files-in-folder-and-subfolder) is similar, though for vb.net (which I don't know). I'd appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction. Many thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [count how many of files in each folder and subfolder then display separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391938/count-how-many-of-files-in-each-folder-and-subfolder-then-display-separately)

Comment: Étienne, thanks for your input and suggesting this link.  I tried, however, couldn't get it to work.  However, thread #5 in this link (https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?288321-Count-Files-in-Folder-amp-Subfolders-have-searched-to-no-avail!) worked perfectly. Counts files in the main folder and all sub-folders.